# How to set Dataframe Column value as X-axis labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

Say I have data in following format:

```
Region   Men   Women
City1    10   5
City2    50   89
```

When I load it in Dataframe and plot graph, it shows index as X-axis labels instead of `Region` name. How do I get names on X-axis?

So far I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
plt.style.use('ggplot')
ax = df[['Men','Women']].plot(kind='bar', title ="Population",figsize=(15,10),legend=True, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel("Areas",fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Population",fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Currently it shows x ticks as `0,1,2..`

Comment: [`plt.xticks()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) [(example)](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html) or [`ax.set_xticklabels()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) might be worth looking into (docs linked for each).  There's also the `xticks` parameter you can specify to [`DataFrame.plot()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

Comment: @jedwards `set.xticklabels()` worked but it's weird showing string vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: Like, the labels are rotated?  In other words, to read them "properly" you'd have to turn your head?  Or the label is very narrow and each letter or two is on a new line.

Comment: like showing `NYC` in stack, `N` on top and `C` at bottom

Comment: @jedwards Check this: http://imgur.com/a/65WCB

Comment: Is that what you want, or what you have?  If that's what you have, do you want them "not rotated"?

Comment: @jedwards I want the region name shows horizontally. I already sent image about what's going wrong.

Comment: That's odd, because for me it defaults to horizontal text.  Does specifying `rotation=0` help at all?  As in, `set_xticklabels(<your_labels>, rotation=0)`?

Comment: @jedwards Perfect! Can you make it as an answer?

Comment: Done -- glad you got it sorted out :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you're using pandas, it looks like you can pass the tick labels right to the  DataFrame's `plot()` method. [(docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).  (e.g. `df.plot(..., xticks=<your labels>)`)

Additionally, since pandas uses matplotlib, you can control the labels that way.

For example with [`plt.xticks()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) [(example)](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html) or [`ax.set_xticklabels()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels)

Regarding the rotation, the last two methods allow you to pass a rotation argument along with the labels.  So something like:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(<your labels>, rotation=0)
```

should force them to lay horizontally.

Answer (score 20):

[plot.bar()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) method inherits its arguments from [plot()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), which has `rot` argument:

from the docs:

> **rot** : int, default None
>
> Rotation for ticks (xticks for vertical,
>   yticks for horizontal plots)

it also uses per default index as ticks for x axis:

> **use_index** : boolean, default True
>
> Use index as ticks for x axis

```
In [34]: df.plot.bar(x='Region', rot=0, title='Population', figsize=(15,10), fontsize=12)
Out[34]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xd09ff28>
```

alternatively you can set index explicitly - it might be useful for multi-level indexes (axes):

```
df.set_index('Region').plot.bar(rot=0, title='Population', figsize=(15,10), fontsize=12)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had a lot of trouble finding an answer I really liked for this, the below function achieves it quite well, and is very adaptable,

```python
def plot_vals_above_titles(data_frame, columns):
    import random
    y_vals = {}

    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.grid(True)

    for index, row in data_frame.iterrows():
        x_coord = 0

        for col in columns:
            # add some jitter to move points off vertical line
            jitter = random.uniform(-0.1,.1)
            x_coord += jitter

            plt.scatter(
                x = x_coord,
                y = row[col]
                )

            x_coord -= jitter
            x_coord+=1

    # rename the xticks with column names
    x_vals = range(0, len(columns))
    plt.xticks(x_vals, columns)
```

Below is an example of my result, though I set a new color for each value in a separate column in the dataframe

[My columns were titled ['A','B','C','D','E']](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZLJI.png)