# pandas: set a column as horizontal axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following row dataset that is containing disparate dates.

```
         Id       Date  Quantity
0  122222ST 2020-10-19      -1.0
1  122222ST 2020-10-22     75.0
2  122222ST 2020-10-22    1100.0
3    100128 2020-10-20       5.0
```

that I want to turn into a time serie for each Id such that every dates are here, if an Id has multiple for a date, they add up, and if there is none, it shows a 0. a minimal reproducible example would like this:

```
Date        122222ST 100128

2020-10-19  -1.0      0
2020-10-20   0        5
2020-10-21   0        0
2020-10-22   1175     0
```

I have been able to do this so far:

```
#read data
df = pd.read_csv('historical_data2.csv', sep=";")

#remove unwanted column
df = df.drop('NetAmount',axis=1)

#set date to datetime 
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

#get unique Ids and sum quantities per date
df = df.groupby(['Id', 'Date']).agg({'Quantity':'sum'}).reset_index()

#adding all missing dates
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D'))
```

From this point on I am stuck because I cannot find a way to set Id values as the horizontal index. I have seen this example [Python Pandas: How to set Dataframe Column value as X-axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38683709/python-pandas-how-to-set-dataframe-column-value-as-x-axis-labels) but it regards plotting which I am interested in. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a pivot_table:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data={"Id":["122222ST",'122222ST','122222ST','100128'],
        "Date":['2020-10-19','2020-10-22','2020-10-22','2020-10-20'],
        "Quantity": [-1,75,1100,50]}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
new_df= pd.pivot_table(df, values='Quantity', index=['Date'],
                    columns=['Id'], aggfunc=np.sum,fill_value=0)



#for missing days (e.g 2020-10-21)
df_Date=pd.date_range(start=new_df.index.min(), end=new_df.index.max(), freq='d')
new_df=new_df.reindex(df_Date,fill_value=0)


print(new_df)
```

result:

```
Id          100128  122222ST
2020-10-19       0        -1
2020-10-20      50         0
2020-10-21       0         0
2020-10-22       0      1175
```

Answer (score 0):

The operation to make the values of a column your new columns is called `pivot`. You have the additional complication that you want to sum quantities if they happen on the same day. This must be done before the pivot operation.
Your solution

```
df = df.groupby(['Id', 'Date']).agg({'Quantity':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

should give the same result but

```
In [11]: df.groupby(['Id', 'Date']).sum().reset_index()                                                                                                                                                    
Out[11]: 
         Id        Date  Quantity
0    100128  2020-10-20       5.0
1  122222ST  2020-10-19      -1.0
2  122222ST  2020-10-22    1175.0
```

is a bit shorter

Then you can just apply `pivot` to the result and use `fillna` to set the not specified values to 0:

```
In [10]: df.groupby(['Id', 'Date']).sum().reset_index().pivot(index='Date', columns='Id').fillna(0)                                                                                                        
Out[10]: 
           Quantity         
Id           100128 122222ST
Date                        
2020-10-19      0.0     -1.0
2020-10-20      5.0      0.0
2020-10-22      0.0   1175.0
```